# Is there a vector length limit in Rstudio?

Tags: r, vector

I was trying to erase specific rows of my data frame. The number of rows I wanted to erase was almost 1,300. When I tried to make a list of these 1,300 row numbers, Rstudio shows me an error.

```
list<-c(3,5,14, 21, 25,28,36, 47, 50, 58, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 124, 125, 127, 134, 135, 136, 147, 150, 158, 161, 169, 180, 190, 191, 202, 206, 209, 213, 218, 236, 258, 264, 279, 280, 281, 291, 302, 313, 324, 336, 347, 348, 358, 369, 374, 391, 397, 402, 413, 422, 424, 434, 435, 436, 447, 456, 458, 460, 473, 480, 491, 502, 513, 521, 524, 527, 533,535, 546, 558, 559, 580, 591, 593, 602, 613, 624, 635, 646, 657, 669, 680, 687, 691, 692, 695, 702, 713, 719, 724, 726, 729, 735, 741, 746, 749, 757, 766, 767, 768, 773, 780, 789, 802, 803, 812, 813, 824, 834, 835, 846, 849, 856, 857, 879, 884, 890, 891, 902, 917, 923, 924, 935, 945, 946, 950, 957, 966, 968, 979, 990, 1001, 1002, 1013, 1024, 1027, 1035, 1040, 1045, 1046, 1057, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1079, 1086, 1090, 1092, 1099, 1101, 1108, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1125, 1136, 1143, 1147, 1151, 1153, 1157, 1158, 1169, 1180, 1183, 1184, 1190, 1191, 1193, 1202, 1213, 1221, 1224, 1236, 1246, 1247, 1258, 1269, 1273, 1280, 1285, 1291, 1302, 1310, 1313, 1322, 1324, 1335, 1336, 1347, 1356, 1358, 1359, 1362, 1369, 1379, 1380, 1387, 1391, 1398, 1402, 1421, 1424, 1435, 1447, 1457, 1458, 1469, 1477, 1486, 1491, 1494, 1502, 1513, 1522, 1524, 1530, 1534, 1535, 1539, 1546, 1551, 1557, 1558, 1567, 1569, 1580, 1587, 1590, 1591, 1602, 1613, 1618, 1624, 1635, 1646, 1653, 1657, 1658, 1668, 1669, 1674, 1680, 1685, 1688, 1691, 1702, 1705, 1713, 1721, 1724, 1735, 1738, 1746, 1752, 1757, 1767, 1768, 1773, 1779, 1791, 1802, 1824, 1827, 1837, 1839, 1840, 1857, 1861, 1879, 1880, 1890, 1906, 1939, 1968, 1988, 2001, 2021, 2046, 2048, 2052, 2057, 2068, 2069, 2079, 2082, 2090, 2101, 2102, 2108, 2112, 2113, 2120, 2124, 2129, 2135, 2146, 2147, 2149, 2150, 2157, 2168, 2179, 2214, 2221, 2224, 2225, 2231, 2238, 2253, 2290, 2296, 2307, 16, 221, 396, 837, 862, 1133, 1418, 1794, 2128, 35, 128, 146, 176, 184,  216,  224, 274, 293, 367, 392, 419, 422, 438, 476, 495, 538, 568, 607, 618, 752, 786, 815, 916, 936, 937, 959, 967, 1083, 1103, 1126, 1172, 1178, 1228, 1240, 1265, 1325, 1343, 1372, 1386, 1397, 1478, 1498, 1512, 1552, 1554, 1556, 1566, 1571, 1660, 1679, 1745, 1836, 1862, 1901, 1931, 1950, 1978, 2029, 2098, 2105, 2136, 2137, 2152, 2235, 2236, 2285, 2288, 2291, 2301, 2320, 2335, 2336, 2339, 2346, 2361, 2372, 2374, 2386, 2406, 2410, 2414, 2419, 2431, 2433, 2443, 2448, 2452, 2461, 2464, 2472, 2481, 2484, 2485, 2496, 2500, 2538, 2540, 2547, 2552, 2557, 2576, 2584, 2594, 2595, 2597, 2600, 2612, 2621, 2631, 2633, 2636, 2701, 2703, 2710, 2715, 2716, 2732, 2736, 2745, 2760, 2761, 2762, 2764, 2766, 2768, 2770, 2772, 2779, 2789, 2792, 2796, 2811, 2826, 2866, 2869, 2874, 2876, 2878, 2896, 2897, 2913, 2922, 2940, 2944, 2949, 2954, 2961, 2964, 2979, 2998, 3001, 3015, 3031, 3033, 3038, 3047, 3058, 3069, 3075, 3084, 3090, 3103, 3122, 3129, 3135, 3147, 3156, 3176, 3208, 3210, 3212, 3214, 3217, 3219, 3227, 3253, 3268, 3271, 3272, 3280, 3282, 3299, 3308, 3309, 3312, 3315, 3317, 3323, 3335, 3374, 3375, 3382, 3383, 3385, 3388, 3413, 3426, 3428, 3432, 3446, 3449, 3460, 3464, 3466, 3470, 3474, 3483, 3487, 3492, 3521, 3525, 3528, 3531, 3536, 3542, 3546, 3553, 3556, 3557, 3563, 3566, 3582, 3584, 3590, 3597, 3612, 3619, 3655, 3664, 3667, 3668, 3669, 3674, 3698, 3703, 3705, 3710, 3712, 3716, 3719, 3749, 3750, 3755, 3773, 3779, 3783, 3792, 3795, 3801, 3817, 3834, 3846, 3854, 3859, 3867, 3871, 3890, 3897, 3898, 3909, 3912, 3941, 3942, 3961, 3965, 3975, 3978, 3994, 4000, 4001, 4018, 4021, 4029, 4049, 4061, 4076, 4077, 4079, 4089, 4094, 4107, 4108, 4110, 4112, 4116, 4118, 4126, 4130, 4141, 4153, 4164, 4179, 4195, 4206, 4211, 4215, 4223, 4228, 4243, 4248, 4249, 4252, 4271, 4312, 4313, 4316, 4325, 4329, 4331, 4334, 4346, 4351, 4365, 4374, 4376, 4381, 4386, 4409, 4416, 4423, 4424, 4425, 4427, 4430, 4432, 4446, 4447, 4501, 4505, 4512, 4518, 4520, 4521, 4544, 4548, 4557, 4575, 4576, 4585, 4598, 4604, 4635, 4665, 4666, 4668, 4689, 4691, 4700, 4709, 4711, 4713, 4714, 4716, 4720, 4725, 4743, 4750, 4753, 4756, 4764, 4775, 4779, 4782, 4784, 4786, 4830, 4836, 4845, 4853, 4870, 4878, 4886, 4887, 4890, 4899, 4900, 4904, 4914, 4937, 4946, 4948, 4999, 5001, 5009, 5016, 5035, 5060, 5067, 5071, 5084, 5103, 5112, 5135, 5141, 5148, 5157, 5161, 5167, 5178, 5201, 5203, 5207, 5217, 5221, 5222, 5223, 5225, 5238, 5255, 5275 ,5291, 5298, 5304, 5315, 5323, 5348, 5376, 5391, 5400, 5404, 5407, 5417, 5418, 5445, 5467, 5471, 5474, 5481, 5497, 5519, 5521, 5529, 5538, 5543, 5549, 5550, 5557, 5563, 5571, 5592, 5618, 5624, 5627, 5630, 5645, 5651, 5656, 5661, 5668, 5677, 5689, 5695, 5696, 5703, 5710, 5730, 5748, 5756, 5759, 5769, 5771, 5774, 5779, 5785, 5803, 5805, 5806, 5807, 5823, 5828, 5838, 5853, 5863, 5880, 5882, 5890, 5891, 5897, 5899, 5903, 5906, 5908, 5916, 5924, 5932, 5933, 5943, 5960, 5961, 5962, 5978, 5979, 5980, 5981, 5992, 5995, 6001, 6002, 6033, 6075, 6081, 6106, 6109, 6112, 6113, 6139, 6140, 6142, 6144, 6147, 6149, 6152, 6162, 6164, 6170, 6172, 6191, 6193, 6198, 6203, 6212, 6223, 6227, 6230, 6236, 6238, 6253, 6256, 6259, 6261, 6262, 6266, 6279, 6280, 6282, 6291, 6334, 6336, 6348, 6351, 6356, 6361, 6378, 6390, 6393, 6394, 6400, 6401, 6413, 6419, 6426, 6427, 6436, 6438, 6439, 6440, 6445, 6451, 6454, 6466, 6483, 6495, 6496, 6499, 6517, 6528, 6540, 6548, 6551, 6552, 6556, 6557, 6583, 6605, 6612, 6617, 6629, 6631, 6642, 6651, 6657, 6665, 6668, 6680, 6684, 6686, 6693, 6711, 6731, 6735, 6751, 6762, 6763, 6767, 6779, 6783, 6793, 6797, 6805, 6809, 6820, 6831, 6842, 6853, 6857, 6864, 6868, 6875, 6886, 6892, 6897, 6898, 6901, 6903, 6904, 6909, 6920, 6922, 6926, 6931, 6942, 6943, 6953, 6961, 6964, 6975, 6977, 6978, 6983, 6984, 6986, 6997, 7006, 7009, 7014, 7018, 7019, 7020, 7031, 7037, 7040, 7042, 7053, 7055, 7064, 7075, 7085, 7086, 7097, 7108, 7110, 7112)
```

After I try to run this line the rstudio shows

```
 +
```

which means I need to type something more. I thought I didn't close the parenthesis, so I tried to closs it.

Then I got the following message.

```
Error in c(3, 5, 14, 21, 25, 28, 36, 47, 50, 58, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74,  : 
 argument 724 is empty
```

When I reduce the number of values in the vector lower than 720, then it doesn't show any error. Like the following row.

```
  list<-c(3,5,14, 21, 25,28,36, 47, 50, 58, 65, 68, 69, 70, 72, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 124, 125, 127, 134, 135, 136, 147, 150, 158, 161, 169, 180, 190, 191, 202, 206, 209, 213, 218, 236, 258, 264, 279, 280, 281, 291, 302, 313, 324, 336, 347, 348, 358, 369, 374, 391, 397, 402, 413, 422, 424, 434, 435, 436, 447, 456, 458, 460, 473, 480, 491, 502, 513, 521, 524, 527, 533,535, 546, 558, 559, 580, 591, 593, 602, 613, 624, 635, 646, 657, 669, 680, 687, 691, 692, 695, 702, 713, 719, 724, 726, 729, 735, 741, 746, 749, 757, 766, 767, 768, 773, 780, 789, 802, 803, 812, 813, 824, 834, 835, 846, 849, 856, 857, 879, 884, 890, 891, 902, 917, 923, 924, 935, 945, 946, 950, 957, 966, 968, 979, 990, 1001, 1002, 1013, 1024, 1027, 1035, 1040, 1045, 1046, 1057, 1067, 1068, 1069, 1079, 1086, 1090, 1092, 1099, 1101, 1108, 1113, 1114, 1115, 1125, 1136, 1143, 1147, 1151, 1153, 1157, 1158, 1169, 1180, 1183, 1184, 1190, 1191, 1193, 1202, 1213, 1221, 1224, 1236, 1246, 1247, 1258, 1269, 1273, 1280, 1285, 1291, 1302, 1310, 1313, 1322, 1324, 1335, 1336, 1347, 1356, 1358, 1359, 1362, 1369, 1379, 1380, 1387, 1391, 1398, 1402, 1421, 1424, 1435, 1447, 1457, 1458, 1469, 1477, 1486, 1491, 1494, 1502, 1513, 1522, 1524, 1530, 1534, 1535, 1539, 1546, 1551, 1557, 1558, 1567, 1569, 1580, 1587, 1590, 1591, 1602, 1613, 1618, 1624, 1635, 1646, 1653, 1657, 1658, 1668, 1669, 1674, 1680, 1685, 1688, 1691, 1702, 1705, 1713, 1721, 1724, 1735, 1738, 1746, 1752, 1757, 1767, 1768, 1773, 1779, 1791, 1802, 1824, 1827, 1837, 1839, 1840, 1857, 1861, 1879, 1880, 1890, 1906, 1939, 1968, 1988, 2001, 2021, 2046, 2048, 2052, 2057, 2068, 2069, 2079, 2082, 2090, 2101, 2102, 2108, 2112, 2113, 2120, 2124, 2129, 2135, 2146, 2147, 2149, 2150, 2157, 2168, 2179, 2214, 2221, 2224, 2225, 2231, 2238, 2253, 2290, 2296, 2307, 16, 221, 396, 837, 862, 1133, 1418, 1794, 2128, 35, 128, 146, 176, 184,  216,  224, 274, 293, 367, 392, 419, 422, 438, 476, 495, 538, 568, 607, 618, 752, 786, 815, 916, 936, 937, 959, 967, 1083, 1103, 1126, 1172, 1178, 1228, 1240, 1265, 1325, 1343, 1372, 1386, 1397, 1478, 1498, 1512, 1552, 1554, 1556, 1566, 1571, 1660, 1679, 1745, 1836, 1862, 1901, 1931, 1950, 1978, 2029, 2098, 2105, 2136, 2137, 2152, 2235, 2236, 2285, 2288, 2291, 2301, 2320, 2335, 2336, 2339, 2346, 2361, 2372, 2374, 2386, 2406, 2410, 2414, 2419, 2431, 2433, 2443, 2448, 2452, 2461, 2464, 2472, 2481, 2484, 2485, 2496, 2500, 2538, 2540, 2547, 2552, 2557, 2576, 2584, 2594, 2595, 2597, 2600, 2612, 2621, 2631, 2633, 2636, 2701, 2703, 2710, 2715, 2716, 2732, 2736, 2745, 2760, 2761, 2762, 2764, 2766, 2768, 2770, 2772, 2779, 2789, 2792, 2796, 2811, 2826, 2866, 2869, 2874, 2876, 2878, 2896, 2897, 2913, 2922, 2940, 2944, 2949, 2954, 2961, 2964, 2979, 2998, 3001, 3015, 3031, 3033, 3038, 3047, 3058, 3069, 3075, 3084, 3090, 3103, 3122, 3129, 3135, 3147, 3156, 3176, 3208, 3210, 3212, 3214, 3217, 3219, 3227, 3253, 3268, 3271, 3272, 3280, 3282, 3299, 3308, 3309, 3312, 3315, 3317, 3323, 3335, 3374, 3375, 3382, 3383, 3385, 3388, 3413, 3426, 3428, 3432, 3446, 3449, 3460, 3464, 3466, 3470, 3474, 3483, 3487, 3492, 3521, 3525, 3528, 3531, 3536, 3542, 3546, 3553, 3556, 3557, 3563, 3566, 3582, 3584, 3590, 3597, 3612, 3619, 3655, 3664, 3667, 3668, 3669, 3674, 3698, 3703, 3705, 3710, 3712, 3716, 3719, 3749, 3750, 3755, 3773, 3779, 3783, 3792, 3795, 3801, 3817, 3834, 3846, 3854, 3859, 3867, 3871, 3890, 3897, 3898, 3909, 3912, 3941, 3942, 3961, 3965, 3975, 3978, 3994, 4000, 4001, 4018, 4021, 4029, 4049, 4061, 4076, 4077, 4079, 4089, 4094, 4107, 4108, 4110, 4112, 4116, 4118, 4126, 4130, 4141, 4153, 4164, 4179, 4195, 4206, 4211, 4215, 4223, 4228, 4243, 4248, 4249, 4252, 4271, 4312, 4313, 4316, 4325, 4329, 4331, 4334, 4346, 4351, 4365, 4374, 4376, 4381, 4386, 4409, 4416, 4423, 4424, 4425, 4427, 4430, 4432, 4446, 4447, 4501, 4505, 4512, 4518, 4520, 4521, 4544, 4548, 4557, 4575, 4576, 4585, 4598, 4604, 4635, 4665, 4666, 4668, 4689, 4691, 4700, 4709, 4711, 4713, 4714, 4716)
```

This problem doesn't happen in R GUI. It only happens when I use R studio. How can I have vector longer than 720? Did I do something wrong?
I am sorry for the cutted example, but I thought it would be better to show the whole list in one line for the easiness of replication.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you type`memory.limit()` to see how much memory is available to `R`?

Comment: It doesn't happen in R GUI because that's a different console than RStudio, which may have different limits.

Comment: Both R and Rstudio shows Inf. They say `memory.limit()` is Window-specific.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich I tried your solution and it works! Do you mean Rstudio has different command line limit than R? I should be careful when I run codes made from R GUI in Rstudio! Thank you!